# How can I update an item in a vector in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

If I have a Vector:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

: and I want to replace the 5 with a 0 to give:

```
[1 2 3 4 0 6 7 8 9]
```

How can I do this when I only know the index as being 4?

Something like:

```
 (replace-in-vec [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] 4 0)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`assoc` works with vectors too!

> ```
>  Usage: (assoc map key val)
>         (assoc map key val & kvs)
> ```
>
> assoc[iate]. When applied to a map,
>   returns a new map of the same
>   (hashed/sorted) type, that contains
>   the mapping of key(s) to val(s). **When
>   applied to a vector, returns a new
>   vector that contains val at index.**
>   Note - index must be <= (count
>   vector).

```
(assoc [1 2 3] 1 :a)
 => [1 :a 3]
```

Comment: And also `update-in`: `(update-in v [4] - 5)`. This is of course a silly example if you just want to reset the five to zero. But it can come in quite handy in case the zero is the result of computation based on the five, eg. moving a coordinate or such.

Comment: Another note: you can also append to a vector with `assoc`. `(assoc [:a :b] 2 :c)` gives `[:a :b :c]`.

Answer (score 6):

You want `assoc`: http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/assoc